# Xamarin Android Firebase with Azure Notification Hub, Registration key invalidating when app is shut

Tags: android, azure, firebase, xamarin, notifications

My application will receive one notification before the GCM registration token will remove the registration with the error "The Push Notification System handle for the registration is no longer valid". What I'm struggling with is working out when it loses the token. If I keep the application open the token stays remains, when I shut it I can receive 1 notification before the token is no longer valid. I feel like it's losing reference to the token somewhere along the way and I'm not entirely sure where.

FireMessagingService Class:

```
[Service]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" })]
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService
{
const string TAG = "MyFirstBaseMessagingService";
private int Notification_ID = 2;
public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)
{
    try
    {
        Log.Debug(TAG, "From: " + message.From);
        if (message.GetNotification() != null)
        {
            Log.Debug(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + message.GetNotification().Body);
            SendNotification(message.Data);
        }
        else
        {
            SendNotification(message.Data);
        }
    } catch (Exception e)
    {

    }
}

void SendNotification(IDictionary<string,string> message)
{
    try
    {
        var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
        intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
        var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);

        Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.GetDrawable(this, Resource.Drawable.lsbu);
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).Bitmap;

        string title = message["title"];
        string body = message["body"];

        NotificationManager notificationManager = GetSystemService(NotificationService) as NotificationManager;
        string ChannelID = GetString(Resource.String.LocalChannelID);
        string AppName = GetString(Resource.String.AppName);
        NotificationImportance Importance = NotificationImportance.Default;
        NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(ChannelID, AppName, Importance);
        notificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(mChannel);

        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this, ChannelID)
                .SetWhen(DateTime.Now.Millisecond)
                .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.miniwozzad)
                .SetLargeIcon(bitmap)
                .SetContentTitle(title)
                .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .SetContentText(body)
                .SetChannelId(ChannelID);

        var notification = builder.Build();
        notificationManager.Notify(Notification_ID, notification);
        Notification_ID++;
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Error: {e.Message}");
    }
  }
}
```

And my FirebaseRegistration Class:

```
[Service]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" })]
public class MyFirebaseIIDService : FirebaseInstanceIdService
{
const string TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";

public MyFirebaseIIDService()
{
    OnTokenRefresh();
}

public override void OnTokenRefresh()
{
    var refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token;
    Log.Debug(TAG, "FCM token: " + refreshedToken);
    SendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
}

void SendRegistrationToServer(string token)
{
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            NotificationHub hub = new NotificationHub(Constants.NotificationHubName, Constants.ListenConnectionString, this.ApplicationContext);

            var tags = new List<string>() { };
            var registration = hub.Register(token, tags.ToArray());
            var regID = registration.RegistrationId;
            Log.Debug(TAG, $"Successful registration of ID {regID}");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
    });
  }
}
```

And finally my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver" android:exported="false" />
    <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver" android:exported="true" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

I'm starting the service last in MainActivity and I get a token in the Console whenever I launch the app so I know I'm getting a token. Any help as to understanding why the token goes when I close the app would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you could follow here to check your configuration for azure notification hubs with FCM:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-android-push-notification-google-fcm-get-started

Comment: I've already looked at these: my keys are all correct because I am receiving notifications, it just when I close the application, I can then send 1 notification and if I try and send a second one, the key invalidates

Comment: Have you solved this problem?